# Is there any way to do multi action button or something similar in swiftui

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to have a button perform a sign in and change a boolean to true with one button. Is there any way to do this is or something similar in SwiftUI?

```
Button(action: {
                NavigationLink(destination: pp()){ EmptyView()}
                    isLoggedIn.toggle()
            }) {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                         .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                         .cornerRadius(5)
                         .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray))
                    Text("Sign up")
                         .foregroundColor(.primary)
                         .font(Font.system(size: 25))
                 }
            }
```

it says :Result of 'NavigationLink<Label, Destination>' initializer is unused

Comment: A `NavigationLink` doesn't belong inside an `action`. It belongs in a view hierarchy. Search "SwiftUI programatic navigation" for lots of solutions